# How do I verify pidgin certificates?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

Pidgin pops a dialog with this occasionally. Where do I go to verify these Google certificates?

```
Certificate Information

Common name: *.google.com

Issued By: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US

Fingerprint (SHA1): 54:a0:1e:03:ff:cb:33:bc:9d:65:dc:d7:bf:6b:04:2b:f9:f3:d5:42

Activation date: Wed Mar 22 12:02:50 2017

Expiration date: Wed Jun 14 11:17:00 2017

SHA256: 4c:41:a2:6d:21:e1:be:63:21:18:01:5d:20:d5:6e:1b:4c:b5:e6:ef:10:6e:af:03:f5:9d:bd:f3:ef:04:0a:ab
```